# How to Django visitor file upload to new sub-directory and directory name should be session name?

Tags: django

I am creating a django application. It has only one model class which is file uploading. It has no user login and registration system.

My goal is to make it so that when someone visits the webpage and upload a file, it creates a new directory inside `"/media"` directory. And the directory name should be unique should also be the session name. Read Carefully:

**When the visitor visits the page and uploads a file, it should create a new directory "A" automatically and even when the visitor reloads the page and uploads another new file, it should create another new directory "B" and store that session's uploaded file on directory "B".**

My `model.py`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ImageForExtractText(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField()
```

and my `form.py`

```
from django import forms
from .models import ImageForExtractText

class UploadImage(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageForExtractText
        fields = [
            'image',
        ]
```

and `view.py`

```
from .forms import UploadImage
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def upload(request):
    form = UploadImage(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

And my `setting.py`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

Hope I was clear on what my issue is and please let me know if anything I said was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function reference to the `upload_to` attribute of  your file field. This function should have a dynamic path (a random directory) and it will be created automatically like this.

```
import os
import uuid
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


def image_path(_, file_name):
    return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(uuid.uuid4()), file_name)


# Create your models here.
class ImageForExtractText(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=image_path)
```

Comment: Thanks For Your solution but i need it should be season name, how can i do this?